# How could an "extra" json element appear in my payload after the http exchange

Tags: java, json, rest, http

Imagine there is chatting software.  A java microservice listens to agents chatting with customers.  The microservice dumps some pertinent data items in an SQS queue.  A java bot reads from the queue, formats some things into the appropriate json and fires this off to a RESTful endpoint outside the network.  Alternatively, in simulation of that bot, I can post manually properly formatted json into postman.  At the last line of appcode before it is sent off in an httpRequestEntity to get a synchronous response before asynchronous processing it can be seen that the json message is properly formed.  This is seen in logging and traffic sniffing.  The same is true if using the postman test harness method.  Some seconds later the package that got sent out of the network arrives at where it was sent.

WITH AN EXTRA JSON ELEMENT!

That reads as if it is metadata from the chatting software!

But remember this happens if the message originates in the chatting software or if I am using the fake cut in line method of mocking the message starting at a later point in the sequence.

I am so stumped.  Every step of the way in every way I know to monitor data along its way the package looks right.  Then at some point it doesn't.  I don't want to bring this up with the people at the other end, receiving the message.  Because it sounds like something that couldn't possible happen.

Please any comments even long shots would be much appreciated.  I will watch this thread and respond to any questions it generates.  Thank you so much.

Comment: It sounds like Mallory's work. Bob and Alice are always complaining she does stuff like that. I would suspect a json serialization framework magically serializing based on a method, annotation, field you are not thinking of, but you said that 'traffic sniffing' (network analyzer?) shows expected json string. So it must be Mallory. Or do you use a queuing or message bus-like service that needlessly 'enriches' your data?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @joshp!  I will go through and do a thorough inventory of all my Annotations.  The json looks valid for as long as I have tools to track.  What I really don't want to bring up is that it could be the receiver/the destination server/software that could be mangling the message.  I want to have all my ducks in a row before I mention something like that.  
I don't know of any message/bus-like services that are involved.  Pretty much json in java over http.  But I will look again at the route from my app through the network paths.